# Use Enum in domain model (ORM) when the corresponding table has set values?

Tags: java, sql, orm, enums, domain-model

I have a table named **job_class** which has set values:

This is the table definition:

```
create table job_class (
   job_class_code int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   job_class_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
   ext_code varchar(10) NOT NULL
)
```

It will always have 3 rows:

```
insert into job_class values (1, 'HOURLY', 'H')
insert into job_class values (2, 'SALARY', 'S')
insert into job_class values (3, 'EXECUTIVE', 'E')
```

**job_class** table is referenced as a FK in **employee** table:

```
create table employee (
   employee_id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   middle_name varchar(50) NULL,
   last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   job_class_code int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES job_class (job_class_code)
)
```

Now to map this table in domain model (ORM), usually I define a class this way:

```
public class JobClass implements java.io.Serializable {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String extCode;

   public Integer getId() { return id; }
   public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

   public String getName() { return name; }
   public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

   public String getExtCode() { return extCode; }
   public void setId(String extCode) { this.extCode = extCode; }
}
```

But what if I define it as `Enum` instead:

```
public enum JobClass {
   HOURLY(1,"HOURLY","H"),
   SALARY(2,"SALARY","S"),
   EXECUTIVE(3,"EXECUTIVE","E");

   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String extCode;

   private JobClass(Integer id, String name, String extCode) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.extCode = extCode;
   }

   public Integer getId() { return id; }
   public String getName() { return name; }
   public String getExtCode() { return extCode; }
}
```

Does it make sense to use a Enum in ORM? I have never used a ENUM directly in ORM before this way. Is it a good practice in this case? What are the Serializable implications if use Enum?

Comment: I am less familiar with Java than other languages, but it should be similar. An enum isn't usually built dynamically like a class. You specify each value at design time. With that said, there may be a way (similar to reflection in .Net) to construct an enum dynamically in memory during run-time, but that is not something normally done. An enum is constructed like this: `public enum MyEnum { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 3 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use an enum you must be 100% sure that your table won't have new record or it's existing record altered, else you will get an error.

With an ORM, you will be able to map to an enum via the  @Enumerated annotation, there are way to do it : EnumType.ORDINAL or EnumType.STRING.

[I'll let you check the documentation for the difference.](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/README.html)

---

In your case since you are using the auto incremented id as a FK key, it would not be good to use `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` as it would force you to name your enum values 1, 2 and 3.

I don't really like to use `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` as it ties your enum order with the database table order. But in your case it would work.

If you want to go the extra miles, you could use a converter     `@Convert(converter = JobClassConverter.class)`

You would keep your enum as it is and the employee's jobClass attribut would look like that :

```
  @Column(name = "job_class_code")
  @Convert(converter = JobClassConverter.class)
  private JobClass jobClass;
```

Then you would create the JobClassConverter

```
public class JobClassConverter implements AttributeConverter<JobClass, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(final JobClass pAttribute) {
        if (pAttribute == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            switch (pAttribute) {
                case HOURLY:
                    return 1;
                case SALARY:
                    return 2;
                case EXECUTIVE:
                    return 3;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JobClass convertToEntityAttribute(final Integer pDbData) {
        if (pDbData == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            switch (pDbData) {
                case 1:
                    return JobClass.HOURLY;
                case 2:
                    return JobClass.SALARY;
                case 3:
                    return JobClass.EXECUTIVE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just updated my opening post to show that job_class is a FK in employee table.

Comment: Did it help you at all ?